# Unrecognized escape sequence CS1009

Tags: c#, razor

I've been trying to build my solution for a website application and i get this code every time from the file Index.g.cshtml.cs, and when i go to the file the line that causes the problem looks like this:

```
WriteLiteral("\r\n        </div>\r\n    </div>\r\n\r\n    <div class=\"col-md-3\">\r\n        <p>This is a fun site to do some buying of dutch products.</p>\r\n    </div>\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \");
```

Can someone please help, it's becoming really frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

Index.g.cshtml.cs is an autogenerated file - open your Index.cshtml file and look for little squiggly red lines that would indicate an error. The error is probably coming from the end of the string (after the div close tag) where you have all of those backslashes. Remove those backslashes, or if you actually need them, then double all of them ("\\" in code will actually display \ to your user)

Comment: <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>This is a fun site to do some buying of dutch products.</p>
    </div>

This is the code inside my Index.cshtml
I don't have squiggly red lines or \ in my code...

Comment: Post your code for Index.cshtml and I can help further.  It looks like this part of the code is probably inside of quotation marks, and it doesn't need to be, but these are just guesses unless you show the code.

Comment: I just had a lot of spaces after the last div element  O__________O, thank's for all of your quick help...
New to this site, excellent response time!!!

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
WriteLiteral(@"\r\n        </div>\r\n    </div>\r\n\r\n    <div class=\"col-md-3\">\r\n        <p>This is a fun site to do some buying of dutch products.</p>\r\n    </div>\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \");
```

Comment: When i write your code it has a syntax error "," expected (before the col-md-3), and a unexpected character \ after the col-md-3

Comment: WriteLiteral(@"\r\n        </div>\r\n    </div>\r\n\r\n    <div class=\""col - md - 3\"">\r\n        <p>This is a fun site to do some buying of dutch products.</p>\r\n    </div>\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \");

Comment: This doesn't change anything. As soon as i change something in the Index.cshtml, it reverts back to the previous state and causes the same problem again.